# Send HTML to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

I've created a javascript function to displays a dialog and receives two parameters for title and body, which will be called from links in a slider.
The thing is I want the body to be able to display HTML code, so you can display links or whatever.
All of this inside a velocity template used in a Liferay portal (just in case it came useful).
This is what i have now:

**JS**:

```
function displayPopup(title, body) {
        $("#more-popup").html(body);
        $("#more-popup").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: title
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**VELOCITY**:

```
#if ($slide.displayPopup.data == true)
    #set( $popupBody = $escapeTool.html($slide.popupBody.data) )
    <a href="#" class="moreButton" onclick="displayPopup('$slide.popupTitle.data', '$slide.popupBody.data')">$moreTextString</a>
#elseif ($slide.Link.data)
    <a href="$slide.Link.data" class="moreButton">$moreTextString</a>
#end
```

I can't come up with a workaround to this. 
First the html was wrong because of the quotes.
After using escaping for HTML entities, the link seems ok, but a javascript exception jumps when clicking on the link: `Uncaught exception: Unexpected Identifier`
Also i don't how to convert back the code to HTML that i can insert in the dialog.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle, basically you need to make your data object an html object instead as at the moment it is probably just passing a string.

Comment: I suspect you'd find this easier if you skipped the velocity and did it all in javascript.

Comment: Can you insert DOM elements rather than HTML string?

Comment: @jdigital: This HAS to be done with velocity, since it's part of a template used to display web content in a Liferay portal.

Comment: @Ginden: The thing is it's to be as generic as posible, since you don't know which exact content you'll need to add to the dialog. It's created using a WYSWIG editor.

Comment: $slide.popupTitle.data needs to have escaped JS code. I'm pretty sure that's your problem. Make sure your escaping code is working properly. Can you print the output of that velocity template with the vars replaced by the real text?

Comment: @AlfaTeK:
- **VELOCITY**:`#set( $popupBody = $escapeTool.html($slide.popupBody.data) )
                    <a href="#" class="moreButton" onclick="displayPopup('$slide.popupTitle.data', '$popupBody')">$moreTextString</a>`
- Generates following **HTML**:
`<a href="#" class="moreButton" onclick="displayPopup('This is the second popup', '&lt;p&gt; This is the second popup's body... and with &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;a link!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;')" id="aui_3_4_0_1_804">More</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it with a workaround but not actually passing the HTML to the function, but creating the div to display the popup for each slide that needs it.

***Velocity***

```
#if ($slide.displayPopup.data == true)
    <a id="more-popup-button-$velocityCount" href="#" class="moreButton popup-button" >$moreTextString</a>
    <div id="more-popup-$velocityCount" class="more-popup" title="$slide.popupTitle.data">
        $slide.popupBody.data
    </div>
#elseif ($slide.Link.data)
    <a href="$slide.Link.data" class="moreButton">$moreTextString</a>
#end
```

***JS***

```
$("#slides a.moreButton.popup-button").click(function (event) {
    var number = $(this).attr("id");
    number = number.substr(number.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    $("#more-popup-" + number).dialog({
        modal: true
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A not-so-good solution is to try this:

```
#if ($slide.displayPopup.data == true)
    #set( $popupBody = $escapeTool.html($slide.popupBody.data) )
    <a href="#" class="moreButton" onclick="displayPopup('$slide.popupTitle.data', "$slide.popupBody.data")">$moreTextString</a>
#elseif ($slide.Link.data)
    <a href="$slide.Link.data" class="moreButton">$moreTextString</a>
#end
```

Notice the " instead of '.

But the real problem is that you are using an HTML escape function where you need a JS escape function that just escapes ' with \' for example... Using HTML escape can give you problems when using your dialog (that you don't see yet because of the JS error).

I don't know how to do this in Velocity but you can start by replacing ' with \'

Comment: First of all, thanks @AlfaTeK.
I use the HTML escaping function because the template generates HTML code; Using the javascript escaping instead produces the next: `                    #set( $popupBody = $escapeTool.javascript($slide.popupBody.data) )` = `&lt;p&gt; This is the second popup\'s body... and with &lt;a href=\" #\"="" id="aui_3_4_0_1_936">a link!&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;`
When this is parsed by the browser, the onclick attribute's content finishes on the href.
I will give it a try to your "not-so-good" solution. ;-)

Comment: :'-( Didn't work. **Result**:
`<a href="#" class="moreButton" onclick="displayPopup('This is the second popup', " &lt;p&gt;="" this="" is="" the="" second="" popup's="" body...="" and="" with="" &lt;a="" link!&lt;="" a&gt;&lt;="" p&gt;")"="" id="aui_3_4_0_1_847">More</a>`
I will try a new approach; i will create a hidden div with each slide containing the needed HTML directly, and when clicking the links will display the appropiate one. Let's see if this works.